# "A" record alias to "A" record alias to apigateway custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53

Having trouble reaching an `apigateway` api via a same-hosted-zone alias record ("A") to a record that aliases an apigateway custom domain. I get `{"message":"Forbidden"}` when I use the latter. The reason I want it to work this way is laziness: I don't want to create a custom-domain + api-mapping + alias for every alias to the same service.

**To sum up:**

*Works*:

- Route53 "A" alias record --> apigateway custom domain

*Doesn't work*:

- Route53 "A" same-hosted-zone alias record --> `Works` above

Comment: You are not explaining yourself properly, what are you tring to do - please show some examples.

Comment: @TheTahaan, I believe all the relevant info is there: including examples of what works and what doesn't. If you believe something specific is missing, please do let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Your configuration should work, Route 53 same-hosted-zone alias record should transitively resolve to whatever you point it to in the same zone. This leads me to suspect something is off in your hosted zone config. Please post the config of your hosted zone via GetHosteZone API call or the like and I will have a look

Comment: @Ryan, the record does resolve properly. I think I'm getting forbidden by apigateway itself.